# Use a C++ file in Cocoa iPhone App

Tags: c++, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use the functionality of the example iPhone app AQOfflineRenderTest in my app (this app specifically isn't important, I just thought it worth mentioning).  I have a C++ file with method called:

```
    void DoAQOfflineRender(CFURLRef sourceURL, CFURLRef destinationURL)
```

I'm trying to call this from my Cocoa Objective-C class.  The example app I referenced above does this by declaring the method in the header file like so:

```
    - (IBAction)doSomethingAction:(id)sender;
    @end
    void DoAQOfflineRender(CFURLRef sourceURL, CFURLRef destinationURL);
```

In the implementation file I call the doSomethingAction which calls renderAudio and executes the same code:

```
    DoAQOfflineRender(sourceURL, destinationURL);
```

When I execute I get the error:
      _DoAQOfflineRender", referenced from:
      -[myViewController renderAudio] in myViewController.o
      symbol(s) not found
      collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Am I missing a reference to this C++ class?  It doesn't specify one in the example app but it runs.

Please help and thanks!

Joe

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I am fighting with it now....   Copied the sample from Apple and use the code exactly as they have in the sample, but getting the error that it can not find the symbol too...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956475/xcode-iphone-program-using-cpp-file-symbol-not-found

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is the implementation of `DoAQOfflineRender` -- did you forget to link in the library where this routine is defined?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using .m as the extension for you Objective-C source file so the compiler thinks you are referencing a C function.  Try changing the extension to .mm.

Answer (score 0):

To call a C++ function from a C or Objective-C file, you must declare it with `extern "C"` linkage in C++.

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void DoAQOfflineRender(CFURLRef sourceURL, CFURLRef destinationURL);

#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The reason for this is that C++ functions’ names are modified by encoding their types, so that functions with the same name but different signatures become different symbols. For example, `DoAQOfflineRender(CFURLRef, CFURLRef)` becomes `__Z17DoAQOfflineRenderPK7__CFURLS1_` without `extern "C"`, but `_DoAQOfflineRender` with it, which is what the C/Objective-C expects.

Comment: Does that mean you can't overload C++ functions and declare them all `extern "C"`?

Comment: That's correct. If you want to overload, use the `.mm` trick to turn the Objective-C file using it into an Objective-C++ file.

Comment: in the example at:  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AQOfflineRenderTest/index.html  a C++ class is used without the declaration you made above.  How do they do it?

Comment: jtbandes: you can’t overload C++ functions declared extern "C", no. Joe: if they’re using a C++ class (as opposed to a function), they must logically be using Objective-C++ rather than Objective-C